# Google Admob Integration Errors

Tags: android, admob

I am working on an app for Android 2.2 Platform, wanted to integrate admob into it, StackOverflow I set up an account downloaded the latest admob SDK and created an ad Layout in XML followed the instructions mentioned in docs. I have set the target in project properties to 1.4 and set the min SDK to 8. Now the error occurs when I configure

```
<activity Android:name="com.Google.ads.AdActivity" Android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

The String

```
keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize
```

wont compile for Android 2.2 it throws errors. However if I compile without these `screenSize|smallestScreenSize`, it compiles but the ad area in the app shows an error saying You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest with configChanges

Can you guys suggest a solution, any help with this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Stupid suggestion: consider not using admob. I hate all those adds. If I see adds in an app, I usually uninstall it or revoke internet permissions.

Comment: Requirement: The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires Android 1.5 or later. Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).

Comment: I have confirmed with the requirement i am building it against  target-14 with minSdk as 8 which is the platform i wish to publish for and yes i have updated the sdk as well  the only issue here is with the configChanges attribute which worked if the minSDK was 14 for 8 the string throws an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google AdMob SDK v4.3.1 requires the additional config changes for optimization on tablets that are running apps with Google AdMob Ads.  The configChanges  `screenSize` and `smallestScreenSize` were not introduced until android-13, so therefore the Google AdMob SDK requires you to COMPILE against Android 3.2 or greater.

You can still make your app run on Android 2.2 devices/emulators by setting the `minSdkVersion` in your manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: I guess there was something wrong with eclipse, the problem got sorted out when i restarted it

Comment: Sometimes the changes takes only effect, when you rebuild the project(s)

Answer (score 0):

set target in project.properties to android-13 (Android v3.2)

not in manifest! (this is that I misunderstood)